# Getting String array from node js to ejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, chart.js, ejs

I'm trying to learn chart.js. So I was trying to make a chart to test out chart.js.

Everything was working fine when I was defining labels directly in the chart.js data. But it didn't work when I tried to retrieve data from mongodb, pass it into `index.ejs`, and then substituting it in the place of labels and data in the script.

Also, when I replaced label by directly giving some labels (not the one received from nodejs) and using the data received from nodejs, it worked.
(Note: country is of String type and value is of Number type in Schema).

The codes for app.js, index.ejs and the output is below.

Thank you!

app.js code:

```
app.get('/', async function (req, res) {

  var countryArr = [];
  var valuesArr = [];

  var getCountry = data.find({}).select('country -_id');
  var getValues = data.find({}).select('value -_id');

  getCountry.exec(function(err, x){
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
      countryArr.push(x[i].country);
    }
    console.log(countryArr);
    getValues.exec(function(err, x){
      for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        valuesArr.push(x[i].value);
      }
      console.log(valuesArr);
      res.render('index',{
        country : countryArr,
        value : valuesArr
      });
    });
  });
});
```

index.ejs

```
<body>
  <p>
    <%= country %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= value %>
  </p>
  <div class="container">
    <canvas id="myChart" style="width: 100px; height=100px"></canvas>
  </div>
  <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    console.log(country[0].toString());
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: [<%= value %>],
        datasets: [{
          label: '#',
          data: [<%= value %>],
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
          ],
          borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
          ],
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

[Browser Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMob0.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found where I was going wrong.

In index.ejs, instead of this...

```
labels: [<%= value %>],
```

It should be...

```
labels: <%- JSON.stringify(country)%>,
```

Basically the array I was receiving from app.js was kind of [abc,xyz,pqr].
So to convert it to a string array like ['abc','xyz','pqr'], we have to use JSON.stringify()

Anyways, thanks folks!